# C++ Unable to get the correct answer for median value

Tags: c++, vector, median

Ok so I created a program that takes in a vector and calculates the median. Although im getting the correct median value for odd number, im not getting the same for even. here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool check;
    cout<<"Hello World";
    vector<double> vec;

    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(6);
    vec.push_back(8);
    vec.push_back(62);

    double median;
    if(check==vec.size()%2)
    {
        median=(vec[vec.size() / 2 - 1] + vec[vec.size() / 2]) / 2;
    }
    else{
         median=vec[(vec.size() / 2.0)];
    }
    cout<<median;
    return 0;
}
```

so when i checked online, the correct answer should be 7 but I get 8.. And this happens only for the even number calculation.. what am i doing wrong i dont get it

Comment: What purpose does `check` serve?

Comment: Especially considering that `check` is uninitialized and therefore have an *indeterminate* value, leading to *undefined behavior* when you use it.

Comment: Why not just `std::nth_element(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + vec.size()/2, vec.end());
    std::cout << "The median is " << vec[vec.size()/2] << '\n';` ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl He already have a sorted data. Now he has a problem to handle case of odd or even size of data.

Comment: @MarekR it's sorted in *this* case, yes. But I wanted to present a *general* solution that does not *depend* on pre-sorted data. As for even vs odd size, I don't believe you need to handle that beyond what I proposed. For an even number of elements, you have to pick either the element before or after the mid point, but which one you pick doesn't really matter and my solution consistently picks the lower. Which should be fine. The only corner case to handle is an empty vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code and cleaned up some unnecessary variable. I per-calculated the array size `n` and the midpoint `centerElement`. You do not want to repeatedly do this calculation specially in scenarios where you have a very large array.

I also removed the boolean variable `check`, which is completely unnecessary. You can find simply compare the output of modulus operation by comparing it with `0`

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main()

{
    vector<double> vec;    
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(6);
    vec.push_back(8);
    vec.push_back(100);
    auto n = vec.size();
    auto centerElement = n/2;

    double median;
    if(n%2 == 0)
    {
        median=(vec[centerElement - 1] + vec[centerElement]) / 2;
    }
    else{
         median=vec[(centerElement)];
    }
    cout<<median;
    return 0;
}
```